# How can I level an old kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, floor, remodeling, hardwood, uneven

I'm trying to level my old hardwood floor in my kitchen to install snap together vinyl on top. I sanded most of the high spots but I would like to use floor leveler to get it nicer.

I sistered the joists underneath with new 2×10's. There are orginal 3/4 planks running perpendicular to the hardwood making the floor 1.5 inches thick total.

I figured I could screw all the hard wood flooring to the planks (with 1.5 inch screws) and screw through both into the joists (3 inch screw) then use the floor leveller.

Would that work? Or should I put down 1/4 plywood over top (screwed through into the joists) and then use the floor leveler? I would like to avoid ripping everything out if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: How out of level is the floor?  LVP is sensitive to dips and  high spots, but level doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you really want *level* —or just flat?